# Set the environment of a function placed outside the .GlobalEnv

Tags: r, module, scope

I want to attach functions from a custom environment to the global environment, while masking possible internal functions.

Specifically, say that `f()` uses an internal function `g()`, then:

1. `f()` should not be visible in `.GlobalEnv` with `ls(all=TRUE)`.
2. `f()` should be usable from `.GlobalEnv`.
3. `f()`  internal function `g()` should *not* be visible and *not* usable from `.GlobalEnv`.

First let us create environments and  functions as follows:

```
assign('ep', value=new.env(parent=.BaseNamespaceEnv), envir=.BaseNamespaceEnv)
assign('e', value=new.env(parent=ep), envir=ep)
assign('g', value=function() print('hello'), envir=ep)
assign('f', value=function() g(), envir=ep$e)

ls(.GlobalEnv)
## character(0)
```

Should I run now:

```
ep$e$f()
## Error in ep$e$f() (from #1) : could not find function "g"
```

In fact, the calling environment of `f` is:

```
environment(get('f', envir=ep$e))
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

where `g` is not present.

Trying to change `f`'s environment gives an error:

```
environment(get('f', envir=ep$e))=ep
## Error in environment(get("f", envir = ep$e)) = ep : 
##   target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Apparently it works with:

```
environment(ep$e$f)=ep
attach(ep$e)
```

Now, as desired, only `f()` is usable from `.GlobalEnv`, `g()` is not.

```
f()
[1] "hello"
g()
## Error: could not find function "g" (intended behaviour)
```

Also, neither `f()` nor `g()` are visible from `.GlobalEnv`, but unfortunately:

```
ls(.GlobalEnv)
## [1] "ep"
```

Setting the environment associated  with  `f()` to `ep`, places `ep` in `.GlobalEnv`.
Cluttering the Global environment was exactly what I was trying to avoid.
Can I reset the parent environment of `f` without making it visible from the Global one?

*UPDATE*
From your feedback, you suggest to  build a package to get proper namespace services.
The package is not flexible. My helper functions are stored in a project subdir, say `hlp`, and sourced like `source("hlp/util1.R")`.
In this way scripts can be easily mixed and updated on the fly on a project basis.

(Added new enumerated list on top)

*UPDATE 2*

An almost complete solution, which does not require external packages, is now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41190862/1851270).

Comment: "Cluttering the Global environment was exactly what I was trying to avoid." Just build a package already.

Comment: @Roland: Please, see the updated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either packages or [modules](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html) do exactly what you want. If you’re not happy with packages’ lack of flexibility, I suggest you give ‘[box](https://klmr.me/box/)’ modules a shot: they elegantly solve your problem and allow you to treat arbitrary R source files as modules:

Just mark public functions inside the module with the comment `#' @export`, and load it via

```
box::use(./foo)
foo$f()
```

or

```
box::use(./foo[...])
f()
```

This fulfils all the points in your enumeration. In particular, both pieces of code make `f`, but not `g`, available to the caller. In addition, modules have [numerous other advantages over using `source`](https://github.com/klmr/modules/wiki/Feature-comparison#source-files-source).

On a more technical note, your code results in `ep` being inside the global environment because the assignment `environment(ep$e$f)=ep` creates a *copy* of `ep` inside your global environment. Once you’ve attached the environment, you can delete this object. However, the code still has issues (it’s more complex than necessary and, as Hong Ooi mentioned, you shouldn’t mess with the base namespace).

Comment: Very interesting approach. Not my intention to mess base namespace, but how can I create a new.env() so that it lives outside the  global one?

Comment: @antonio As mentioned briefly in my answer, you can `attach` the environment and then `rm` the reference to it. This can be done in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't be messing around with the base namespace. Cluttering up the base because you don't want to clutter up the global environment is just silly.*

Second, you can use `local()` as a poor-man's namespacing:

```
e <- local({
    g <- function() "hello"
    f <- function() g()
    environment()
})

e$f()
# [1] "hello"
```

* If what you have in mind is a method for storing package state, remember that (essentially) anything you put in the global environment will be placed in its own namespace when you package it up. So don't worry about cluttering things up.

Comment: There is a reason to enclose `f`, `g`, in separate environments: attaching  only the `f` environment and make only `f` usable from Global environment (see updated question).   
As regards dirtying the base env, how can I create an environment that does not show with `ls(all=TRUE)`?

Comment: `local` doesn’t do any namespacing, it just makes OP’s assignment code easier to write …