# R: Source personal scripts keeping some functions hidden

Tags: r, module, scope, package, scoping

Follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41133617/1851270)

I want to source scripts inside a given environment, like in `sys.source`, but  "exporting" only some functions and keeping the others *private*.

I created  this function:

```
source2=function(script){ 
    ps=paste0(script, "_")
    assign(ps, new.env(parent=baseenv()))
    assign(script, new.env(parent=get(ps)))    
    private=function(f){
        fn=deparse(substitute(f))
        assign(fn, f, parent.env(parent.frame()))
        rm(list=fn, envir=parent.frame())
    }
    assign("private", private, get(script))
    sys.source(paste0(script, ".R"), envir=get(script))
    rm(private, envir=get(script))
    attach(get(script), name=script)
}
```

For the most part, this function works as expected.
Consider the script:

```
## foo.R
f=function() g()
g=function() print('hello')
private(g)
```

Note the `private()` function, which will hide `g()`.

If I, so to say, *import the module* `foo`:

source2("foo")

I have a new environment in the search path:

```
search()
##  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "foo"               "package:stats"    
##  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
##  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
## [10] "package:base"
```

The current environment, `.GlobalEnv`, shows only:

```
ls()
## [1] "source2"
```

But if I list items in `foo` environment:

```
ls("foo")
## [1] "f"
```

Therefore I can run:

```
f()
## [1] "hello"
```

The problem is that `g()` is hidden totally.

```
getAnywhere(g)
## no object named 'g' was found
```

Too much. In fact, if I want to debug `f()`:

```
debug(f)
f()
debugging in: f()
## Error in f() : could not find function "g"
```

The question is:
Where is `g()`? Can I still retrieve it?

Comment: and we're not just making a package why?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: please, see the first updated in the link set  in question head and the accepted answer

Comment: this one is long enough, thx. you're hack-replicating functionality inherent in packages and it takes virtually no extra time to make a pkg or update a pkg.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Yes it is a hack, but I think the increasing number of R module packages is a proof that these  [design principles](https://github.com/klmr/modules/wiki/Design-rationale) are well grounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
get("g",env=environment(f))
## function ()
## print("hello")
## <environment: 0x0000000018780c30>

ls(parent.env(environment(f)))
## [1] "g"
```

Credit goes to Alexander Griffith for the solution.